# Find the smallest integer $n > 0$ such that $2012$ divides $9^n-1$.

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest integer $n > 0$ such that $2012$ divides $9^n-1$.

---

my thoughts:

$$2012=2 \cdot 2 \cdot 503$$
$503$ is prime. so by fermats little theorem $9^{502} \equiv 1$(mod $503$). again $9^n \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
hence for $n=502$ equality holds but is it the smallest?

Comment: $9^n-1=8(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}+....+1)$ The second term$((9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}+....+1))$ has to be a multiple of $503$.

Comment: The smallest could be a divisor of 502. Actually, it's 251.

Comment: @arbautjc: And that proves it. $251$ is a prime.

Comment: how can I able to show that 251 satisfies the equation.

Comment: Simply write $503 \ |\  3^{502}-1$ as 503 is prime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$9^{502} \equiv1\mod503 \Longrightarrow$

$ 9^{502}-1\equiv0\mod503 \Longrightarrow $

$(9^{251}-1)(9^{251}+1)\equiv0\mod503 \Longrightarrow$

By fermat's theorem, $3^{502} \equiv1\mod503$

GCD $((9^{251}-1),(9^{251}+1))=2 \Longrightarrow$

$503\not\mid (9^{251}+1)$

Therefore, $9^{251}-1\equiv0\mod503$.

Smallest $n=251$. As $9^1 \neq 1 \mod 503$.

Comment: @Inceptio. I had this answer in mind. But how do you decide that 503 divides the first factor, not the second ? Actually the GCD is not even necessary since 503 is prime.

Comment: Thats just because $3^{502}\equiv1\pmod {503}$. From the the same fermat's theorem.

Comment: Ok, but your answer has nothing to do with this last argument ;-)

Comment: Yeah! . I assumed people know the theorem. :P

Comment: @inceptio, how do you establish that prime $503\not\mid (9^{251}+1)?$

Comment: $3^{502}\equiv1\pmod {503}$ right? Which means the other factor doesn't divide $503$, as the G.C.D is $2$ and $503$ is prime.!

Comment: @Inceptio, but this logic is not included in the answer. Also, $9^{251}\equiv1\pmod{503}$ does not imply that $251$ is the smallest positive integer unless you show by the prime nature of $251$

Comment: Prime nature of $251$, I need to show that $9^1 \neq 1\mod 503$ ?, I assumed, it is understood?

Comment: @Inceptio. But the argument $503 \ | \ 3^{502}-1$ is enough alone, and your answer does not add anything. From GCD you can't conclude anything. It's like saying "1+1=2, therefore 5 is prime (oh, by the way, it's prime because it's not divisible by 2 or 3, but you were smart enough to know that)". Your *Therefore* is meaningless.

Comment: Its like if by any chance, any moment the $503$ starts dividing the other term. Causes a trouble, therefore better be careful of that. ;). Take an example $(a+1).(a-1)= 0 mod(5)$ , But you don't know which divides 5. Therefore, taking G.C.D helps.

Comment: But even if $503 \ | \ 9^{251}+1$ *by any chance*, we don't care! You know already that the one you're intereted in is divisible by 503, period.

Comment: That has to be $9^{251}+1$ right? But if this is divisible by $503$, the other won't by divisible by $503$ unless or otherwise G.C.D is $503k$.?

Comment: Yep, you're right :-)

Answer (score 2):

$503$ is a [Sophie Germain prime,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) i.e. $\rm\: q = 503 = 2p\!+\!1 \:$ for prime $\rm\:p = 251,\:$ so order computation mod $\rm\,q\,$ is easy. We prove it generally (more insightful and just as easy). Yours is $\rm\: m=4,\ a= 9.$

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\rm\,\ p,\, q=2p\!+1\:$ are primes, and $\rm\ m\mid a\!-\!1,\,\ q\nmid a,a^2\!-\!1\:$ then

$$\rm ord_{qm}(a)\ =\ p\ \ \ if\ \  a\ \  is\ a\ square\ mod\ q,\ \  else\ \ 2p$$

**Proof** $\ $ First, note that $\rm\:(q,m)=1\:$ (else $\rm\ q\mid m\mid a\!-\!1\mid a^2\!-\!1)\,\:$ contra hypothesis). Therefore

$$\rm\:qm\mid a^n\!-\!1\iff q,m\mid a^n\!-\!1\iff q\mid a^n\!-\!1,\ \ \ since\ \ \ m\mid a\!-\!1\mid a^n\!-\!1.\:$$

So $\rm\: ord_{qm}(a) = ord_q(a) =: n.\,$ $\rm\,mod\ q\!:\ 1 \equiv a^{q-1}\! \equiv a^{2p},\:$ so $\rm\:n\mid 2p.\:$ By hypothesis $\rm\:q\nmid a^2\!-\!1,\:$ so $\rm\:n\nmid 2.\:$  If $\rm\:n = p\:$ then $\rm\:1 \equiv a^p \equiv a^{(p-1)/2},\:$  true iff $\rm\:a\:$ is a square $\rm\:mod\ q,\:$  by [Euler's Criterion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)

Comment: Awesome. Use of Sophie Germain prime fascinates me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem , $3^{502}\equiv1\pmod {503}$
$\implies (3^2)^{251}\equiv1\pmod {503}$
$\implies 9^{251}\equiv1\pmod {503}$

As we know, if $a^n\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $ord_na=d, d\mid n$ where integer $n>0$ ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213361/showing-mathrmord-da-mid-mathrmord-ma-if-d-mid-m/213456#213456))

If $ord_{503}9=d\implies d\mid 251$

As $251$ is prime, $d=1$ or $251$

As $9^1\not\equiv1\pmod {503} ,d=251$